# F# query for "doesn't contain"

Tags: f#

There's a query to search for when an item is contained in a list, but there isn't one for when an item isn't.

This query finds `customer` objects which don't have `ContactNum` in the given list `cdiffnums`. What could I do to return just the customers that *dont* have a `ContactNum` in this list?

```
let q =
    query {
        for c in dc.Customers do
        where (query { for n in cdiffnums do contains c.ContactNum })
        select c
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My F# is rusty, but have you tried:

```
let q =
    query {
        for c in dc.Customers do
        where (not (query { for n in cdiffnums do contains c.ContactNum }))
        select c
    }
```

Comment: Correction - In F#, negation is done using `not` function instead of the `!` operator (as in C#). The `!` operator is used to get the value of a reference cell. I did not test the code, but I think it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I think smth like this should work:

```
open System.Linq

let cdiffnums = [|1;2;3|]
let q =
    query {
        for c in dc.Customers do
        where (not (cdiffnums.Contains c.ContactNum))
        select c
    }
```